Identity of Schur polynomials
Let $p_n$ be the power sum symmetric polynomial,
$$p_n=x_1^n+x_2^n+\dots x_n^n$$
in $n$ variables, and let $s_\lambda$ be the Schur polynomials. I am new to Schur polynomials so I'm not sure what properties I should use to prove the following identity:

$$p_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(-1)^{k-1}s_{(n-k,1,1,\dots,1)}$$
(where $(n-k,1,1,\dots,1)$ has $k$ ones)?

Would anyone help me out with this or give some hint?

Please show what you tried, it is the way it works. For instance, what happens in the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$? (Maybe also $n=4$.) See also https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question - it is very important to provide content.

@dan_fulea I tried computing the generating function of both sides. The LHS is easy, but the RHS I don't know how to deal with. It looks some kind of convolution but I'm unfamiliar with those polynomials and from the definition it looks complicated to compute it

I also tried induction but to no avail

What is your definition of $s_\lambda$? If you know the definition in terms of semi-standard Young tableaux, then, hint: try a sign reversing involution argument. Think about the position of the highest entry.

For $n=3$ we have the equality $$p_3=s_3-s_{21}+s_{111}$$ (in three variables) and i am missing one term. The sum is alternating, we are getting $x^3$ and its cousins only from $s_3$, which should come with plus.

(Murnaghan–Nakayama rule, special case.)

To illustrate a possible idea to proceed, i will consider first a special case, not too small, not too big, $n=5$, and the five variables are $x,y,z,u,v$.
The Vandemonde determinant for the five variables is denoted by $\Delta$.
The Vandemonde determinant for the four variables $y,z,u,v$ remained by eliminating $x$ is denoted by $\Delta^x$. Similarly, $s^x_\lambda $ stays for
$s_\lambda$ applied for the remained variables, after removing $x$ from their list.
Below i am using the property that the Schur polynomials
$s_1$, $s_{11}$, $s_{111}$, $s_{1111}$, ... are the elementary polynomials $e_1,e_2,e_3,e_4$. So for instance, when applied on $y,z,u,v$ we have
$s_1=e_1=\sum y=y+z+u+v$,
$s_{11}=e_2=\sum yz$,
$s_{111}=e_3=\sum yzu$,
$s_{1111}=e_3=\sum yzuv=yzuv$.
Below, a cyclic sum w.r.t. the variables $x,y,z,u,v$ is denoted by $\sum'$.

Then  we have the Schur polynomials $s_\lambda$, determined by
(a possible definition (Jacobi's_bialternant_formula)):
$$
\begin{aligned}
s_5\cdot\Delta   &= 
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
x^9 & y^9 & z^9 & u^9 & v^9\\
x^3 & y^3 & z^3 & u^3 & v^3\\
x^2 & y^2 & z^2 & u^2 & v^2\\
x   & y   & z   & u   & v  \\
1   & 1   & 1   & 1   & 1  \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right]
=\sum'x^9\cdot \Delta ^x
\ ,
\\
s_{41}\cdot\Delta  &= 
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
x^8 & y^8 & z^8 & u^8 & v^8\\
x^4 & y^4 & z^4 & u^4 & v^4\\
x^2 & y^2 & z^2 & u^2 & v^2\\
x   & y   & z   & u   & v  \\
1   & 1   & 1   & 1   & 1  \\
\end{smallmatrix}\right]
=\sum'x^8\cdot s^x_1\cdot \Delta ^x
=\sum'x^8\cdot \left(\sum y\right)\cdot \Delta ^x
\ ,
\\
s_{311}\cdot\Delta  &= 
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
x^7 & y^7 & z^7 & u^7 & v^7\\
x^4 & y^4 & z^4 & u^4 & v^4\\
x^3 & y^3 & z^3 & u^3 & v^3\\
x   & y   & z   & u   & v  \\
1   & 1   & 1   & 1   & 1  
\end{smallmatrix}\right]
=\sum'x^7\cdot s^x_{11}\cdot \Delta ^x
=\sum'x^7\cdot \left(\sum yz\right)\cdot \Delta ^x
\ ,
\\
s_{2111}\cdot\Delta  &= 
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
x^6 & y^6 & z^6 & u^6 & v^6\\
x^4 & y^4 & z^4 & u^4 & v^4\\
x^3 & y^3 & z^3 & u^3 & v^3\\
x^2 & y^2 & z^2 & u^2 & v^2\\
1   & 1   & 1   & 1   & 1  
\end{smallmatrix}\right]
=\sum'x^6\cdot s^x_{111}\cdot \Delta ^x
=\sum'x^6\cdot \left(\sum yzu\right)\cdot \Delta ^x
\ ,
\\
s_{11111}\cdot\Delta  &= 
\left[\begin{smallmatrix}
x^5 & y^5 & z^5 & u^5 & v^5\\
x^4 & y^4 & z^4 & u^4 & v^4\\
x^3 & y^3 & z^3 & u^3 & v^3\\
x^2 & y^2 & z^2 & u^2 & v^2\\
x   & y   & z   & u   & v 
\end{smallmatrix}\right]
=\sum'x^5\cdot s^x_{1111}\cdot \Delta ^x
=\sum'x^5\cdot \left(\sum yzuv\right)\cdot \Delta ^x
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

We build now the alternating sum. Since $(X-y)(X-z)(X-u)(X-v)$ is a polynomial in $X$ with coefficients the elementary symmetric functions in $(y,z,u,v)$ we can group:
$$
\begin{aligned}
&(s_5-s_{41}+s_{311}-s_{2111}+s_{11111})\Delta
\\
&\qquad=\sum'x^5\cdot \underbrace{(x-y)(x-z)(x-u)(x-v)\Delta^x}_{=\Delta}
\\
&\qquad=\left(\sum'x^5\right)\Delta
\\
&\qquad=\left(x^5+y^5+z^5+u^5+v^5\right)\Delta\ .
\end{aligned}
$$

The general case can be shown in a similar manner. We use the definition
(Jacobi's_bialternant_formula) for each involved Schur polynomial,
Laplace-expand w.r.t. the first row containing the higher powers, the Schur polynomials $s_{11\dots1}$ that appear are elementary polynomials, we obtain a factorization corresponding to $X^n-s_1(y,\dots)X^{n-1}+\dots\pm e_n(y,\dots)=\prod (X-y)$, and this is exactly $\Delta/\Delta^x$.
$\square$

Here is a sign-reversing involution argument. Recall that a semi-standard Young tableaux of shape $\lambda$, for a partition $\lambda$, is a filling of the Young diagram of $\lambda$, with natural numbers that are weakly increasing across rows and strictly increasing down columns. Then $s_\lambda$ can be defined as the sum $s_\lambda = \sum_{T} x^T$, where $T$ is the set of semi-standard Young tableaux (SSYT) of shape $\lambda$ and $x^T = x_1^{n_1}\cdots x_k^{n_k}$ where $n_i$ is the number of entries equal to $i$. Let $S$ be the set of all SSYT of shape $\lambda$ for $\lambda$ of hook-shape, that is, $\lambda = (n-k, 1,1,\ldots, 1)$ with $k$ 1's, for $k = 0, \ldots, n-1.$
Now define a map $\omega: S\to S$ as follows.

If $T$ has all entries equal, $\omega(T) = T$.
Otherwise, let $m$ be the largest entry of $T$.

If $m$ is on the vertical column of $T$, then $\omega(T) = T'$ where $T'$ has the last entry of the vertical column moved to the end of the first row.
Otherwise, $m$ must appear at the end of the first row.  Define $T'$ by moving this entry to the end of the first column and set $\omega(T) = T'$. (Check that this still produces an SSYT.)



For example
$$T = \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 2 & 4 \\
2 & \\
4 &
\end{array}$$
maps to
$$\omega(T) = T' = \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 2 & 2 & 4 & 4\\
2 & \\
\end{array}$$
and similarly $\omega(T') = T$.
It's clear that $\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{k-1}s_{k, 1, \ldots, 1} = \sum_{T \in S} (-1)^{k(T)-1}$ where $k(T)$ is defined so that $k(T) = k$ for $T$ of shape $\lambda = (k, 1, \ldots, 1)$. Then we see that $\omega$ is a bijection from $S$ to itself that maps any $T$ with not all entries equal to another $T$ of this kind with opposite sign in the sum, without changing the weight $x^T$. It follows that all of these cancel in the sum and we are left with only the tableaux of shape $(n)$ with all entries equal left, and the sum is then $p_n$. So $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1} (-1)^{k-1}s_{n-k, 1, \ldots, 1} = p_n.$$ (Note that we actually include $k=0$, unlike in your identity, which is slightly incorrect.)
